# asp.net core 2.1 with knockout

Tags: asp.net-core, knockout.js

I've been trying to teach myself the ins and outs of .NET Core development, and I've got the start of a Core 2.1 web application created. I've even gotten the hang of EF Core, and have a working DB Context. I am, however, having difficulty figuring out how to implement knockout. I ran the command

dotnet add ProjectName package knockoutjs --version 3.4.2

(with my actual Project Name of course), and it seems to have successfully added knockout under the Dependencies / NuGet node. Clicking on the "knockoutjs (3.4.2), I can see the path where the files are stored (it seems to have stored them in a central location, to be used for all projects).

What I can't figure out is, how do I actually reference the knockout js file? In my previous (non Core) projects, it was as simple as adding a script src, pointing to the js file path, but I can't figure out where that is. I would have expected it to show up somewhere under wwwroot/lib, but I don't see the knockout js file listed there (or anywhere else for that matter). Am I missing a step to get the js file to show up under wwwroot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately,  the `dotnet add package` only manages the server-side code now . As a result , those client packages  installed by `nuget`/`dotnet add package` are located somewhere outside of our project and you can't find them under the `wwwroot/` .

For those client dependencies , it's better to use `npm` or `LibMan`. As the name suggests , the [`LibMan`](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager)  is a Library Manager developed by Microsoft used to install and consume client dependencies . You can install the `CLI` tool by `dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli`

To install knockoutjs with `LibMan` , simply use the command below :

```
libman install knockout
```

And the `knockout-debug.js` , `knockout-min.js` will be there :

```
dir wwwroot/lib/knockout

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        9/11/2018  12:38 PM         289595 knockout-debug.js
-a----        9/11/2018  12:38 PM          60354 knockout-min.js
```

if you prefer a GUI way , you can refer the [wiki by Microsoft](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/wiki/Using-LibMan-in-Visual-Studio)

Comment: I installed libman, but when I try "libman install knockout", it just sits there and appears to be hung up. After several minutes, I closed VS, reopened and retried it, but it still hangs. I even tried a brand new project, with the same result. Any ideas?

I could try npm - what is the command for installing that?

Comment: @Kurt , To install with LibMan cli tool , simply use a plain terminal (command line , powershell ) , don't use the package manager console within Visual Studio   . To  install with npm , just type `npm i knockout` , see [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knockout) here .

Comment: thanks for clearing that up - I ran libman from a command prompt and it worked. I see there is even a libman.json in the project root. Thanks for the help!