# How to reference lodash in my dot net core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

how can i reference lodash in my dot net core project.
I've created a new dot net core web application and installed lodash using nuget package manager.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.0.415" />
    <PackageReference Include="lodash" Version="4.17.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="newtonsoft.json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  </Project>
```

My question is, now that i have a reference to lodash in my .csproj file, how can i use lodash in my app?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267120/asp-net-core-2-1-with-knockout/52268894#52268894

Comment: @itminus thank you so much! Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to import the namespace you are interested in and work with it . Example to get current date

```
using System;
using Lodash.Net.Methods;

var loadDashDAte = new LodashDate();

// Gets the timestamp of the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch (1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

var currentDate = loadDashDate.Now();

Console.WriteLine(currentDate.ToString());
```